# How to combine two associate arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge, associative-array

I have two associate arrays. I want to combine both. I want to group them to make only one .

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [min] => 6
            [price] => 100.000
            [sale_price] => 99.000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [min] => 10
            [price] => 100.000
            [sale_price] => 95.000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [min] => 20
            [price] => 100.000
            [sale_price] => 80.000
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [min] => 10
            [your_price] => 94.000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [min] => 15
            [your_price] => 92.000
        )
   [2] => Array
        (
            [min] => 25
            [your_price] => 75.000
        )
)
```

Now my output should be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [min] => 6
            [price] => 100.000
            [sale_price] => 99.000
            [your_price] => NA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [min] => 10
            [price] => 100.000
            [sale_price] => 95.000
            [your_price] => 94.000

        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [min] => 15
            [price] => NA
            [sale_price] => NA
            [your_price] => 92.000

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [min] => 20
            [price] => 100.000
            [sale_price] => 80.000
            [your_price] => NA
        )

   [4] => Array
        (
            [min] => 25
            [price] => NA
            [sale_price] => NA
            [your_price] => 75.000
        )
)
```

Is there any function in php that can do this work ?

Keep searching on my own .

Help will be appreciated.

Thank you .

Comment: Well, take a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)..

Comment: Post your attempts. What you have tried so far

Comment: I have tried array_merge function.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **array_merge** function:

```
$output = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

That should make the work you need .

**EDIT :**

```
$ output = $array1 + $array2
```

Easyer way to do it but efficient too.

See **[this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp)** website for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**PHP**:array_merge](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp)

```
array array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )
```

Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

Comment: I have tried this. array_merge function just copy both array in an array. It does not meet my requirement.

Comment: How did you implement? I think you must merge the elements of the inner array first.